# Gridded population data by income level

Tags: geospatial, income

I am looking for a geospatial dataset with population density by income level, ideally spatially disaggregated. so each pixel has the population count or desnity of [0-1$/day],[1-2$/day], [2-4$/day] ... [Jeff Bezos $/day]

I found the following [data](https://ourworldindata.org/global-economic-inequality) at a country level:

[image]

any leads?

UPDATE: I found the following resources:
[link1](https://www.gapminder.org/data/documentation/income-mountains-dataset/)
[link2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/factfulness-building-gapminder-income-mountains/)

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5800392/#__sec9title may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can combine the indicators EN.RUR.DNST ("Rural population density (rural population per sq. km of arable land") and SI.SPR.PCAP  ("Survey mean consumption or income per capita, total population (2011 PPP $ per day))" provided by the [World Bank's Indicators API](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/889392-about-the-indicators-api-documentation)  . These datasets are resolved on a on a per-country basis not on a "per-pixel" basis.